# `yarn install` is changing my repo's .git/config file. How can I track down why?

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I've cloned a repo from GitHub (microsoft/azuredatastudio), and whenever I run `yarn install`, at the end of that 60 second process, my repository-local config file (`ADS/.git/config`) changes (specifically, `pull.rebase` gets set to `true`).

How can I investigate what part of `yarn install` is changing my pull method and stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the repo's package.json had a postinstall step defined, which contained `cp.execSync('git config pull.rebase true');`